# Bootstrap tooltip not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm trying to show my tooltip but it is not working. What have I tried

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip">Hyperlink Text</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip({
        title: "<h1 style='background-color: #F00; color: #000;'>This is a test tooltips</h1>",
        html: true,
        placement: "bottom",
        trigger: "click"
    });
});
```

My bootstrap version `3.3.5` and jQuery version `1.11.3`

Where is my issue? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is perfect, except you have given option as `trigger:click`, for your `tooltip` to be visible.

**Without `trigger:click` - displays tooltip on hover**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#togle').tooltip({
      title: "<h1 style='background-color: #F00; color: #000;'>This is a test tooltips</h1>",
      html: true,
      placement: "bottom"
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="togle" data-toggle="tooltip">Hyperlink Text</a>
```

**With `trigger:click`- displays tooltip on click**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#togle').tooltip({
      title: "<h1 style='background-color: #F00; color: #000;'>This is a test tooltips</h1>",
      html: true,
      placement: "bottom",
      trigger:"click"
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="togle" data-toggle="tooltip">Hyperlink Text</a>
```

Comment: @Rao it worked after adding `3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css` instead of version `3.3.5`. Click wasn't  susceptible to the problem

Comment: Great.. Happy coding Janie.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

**To create a tooltip, add the data-toggle="tooltip" attribute to an element.**

Use the **title** attribute to specify the text that should be displayed inside the tooltip:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

but in your case title is missing. Add a title and try again.

[Working Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)

Comment: As a complement, If she wants to customize the style of the tooltip, you can use template, but title is still required.

Comment: Ya, because the text in title will show as a tooltip that's why it is required

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz it just shows the title `Hooray!` but not my customized title `This is a test tooltips`

Comment: @janie, you can use template attribute to customize the title... `template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>' `

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz thanks for your attempt. I solved my problem. :)

Comment: Sounds great :)